# How can I use a variable in another file on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use my variable in all files of my program.
this is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
 main.rb
 Class1
 def self.test1
 puts "class 1" if @@debug
  end
 end
 @@ debug = true

 class.test1
 class.test2

 class2.rb
 Class2
 def self.test2
 puts "test2" if @@debug
  end
 end
```

I really hope  it's enough clear for the community, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a global variable or constant. You could create your own, but Ruby conveniently comes with a builtin `$DEBUG` global variable. When you specify the `-d` option to `ruby`, `$DEBUG` will be `true`, and otherwise, `false`.

If the classes are in multiple files, put this in the file that includes the others:

```
DEBUG=$DEBUG
```

And in the other files, use `DEBUG` for debug, rather than `$DEBUG`.

Comment: i want a global variable but in the other file it doesn't work --"

Comment: @TakezoShinmen: And how are you connecting these files? Require? Nothing will work without `require`.

Comment: @TakezoShinmen: Show me the `require`.

Comment: Maybe it is not clear enough, that you do not need to build your own debug mechanism. simply check for `$DEBUG` and run your program with `ruby -d prog.rb` when you want the debug output and with `ruby prog.rb` when you don't want it. No need for class variables etc.

Comment: @Linuxios these are my require: require 'qark_stat',require 'qark_matrix'
padde i have to create $DEBUG and only type -d for using it ?

Comment: @TakezoShinmen: Yes. You don't have to create `$DEBUG`. Just run Ruby with the `-d` option.

Comment: @padde Well in fact, i didn't type -d but just put $DEBUG and it's okay thank you!

Comment: @Linuxios I try to run with -d but it makes an error so i give up :s thanks for reply

Comment: @Linuxios, this one : "stagiaire@stagiaire-desktop:~/NetBeansProjects/qosenergy_trunk/lib/qark$ ruby -d main.rb 1
main.rb:292: warning: useless use of a literal in void context
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1340 - no such file to load -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36 - no such file to load -- rsruby
main.rb:81: warning: method redefined; discarding old inspect
main.rb:793: warning: instance variable @debug not initialized
"

Answer (score 1):

You can create a getter method to get class_variable

```
def self.get_debug
  @@debug
end
```

rails however provides a method called cattr_accessor
http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor
This will allow you to set and get the class variable outside the class

i.e.  `Class1.debug = false`

Comment: ,I try it but i have an undifined method :s